# React Router not updating history when a ref is used in a component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am navigating from Page A to Page B and using history listener from react router to get the current location path. Page A has an audio element with a ref set. When I navigate back from Page B to Page A, the location listener is not fired and history is not updated.
The setup is fairly simple.
I have noticed that when I remove the ref from the audio tag and make no other change, everything works fine as expected.

```
const audioRef = useCallback((node: HTMLAudioElement)=>{

    ..some audio playing logic

},[])
<audio ref={audioRef} src={url} preload='metadata' ></audio>
```

Can someone please help me get around this?